# Source code formatter for Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, tools

Most programming languages have tools to format source code according to convention: for example, Python has [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8) and [yapf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yapf), and Go has [gofmt](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/).

Does a similar tool exist for Solidity source code, ideally according to the [Solidity Style Guide](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/style-guide.html)?

Comment: It may be better to ask this on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Would be on-topic for both sites. I like it.

Comment: would love to see this in JetBrains suite, specifically PyCharm !

Answer (score 17):

I've recently published a Linter for Solidity which aims to comply the the official Style Guide.

Here's the [repo](https://github.com/duaraghav8/solium)

The architecture is pretty similar to that of ESLint so I'm trying to make it as easy-to-use and customizable (including plugging in of custom rules) as ESLint is.

Its under active development right now.

To get started, you could install it via npm:

```
npm install -g solium
```

Browse to the root directory of your project and run

```
solium --init
```

This creates `.soliumrc.json` (determines which rules to enable and handles plugging in of custom rules) & `.soliumignore` (specifies which files and folders to ignore)

To run the linter on a single file, simply use:

`solium --file path/to/myfile.sol`

To lint over your entire project (all .sol files), use:

`solium`

OR

`solium --hot`
to enable hot reloading.

Hopefully, this improves workflow & developer productivity, since I've been facing a lot of trouble developing for Ethereum platform, because of the lack of dev tools.
Hope you find it useful!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Does Solium only do linting, or can it reformat files too?

Comment: @PiDelport I'm not sure what you mean by reformatting. Do you mean fixing the lint errors automatically? (If yes, then) I'm currently in the process of implementing a fix mechanism, so in a week or so, yah, it will support fixing.

Comment: Basically that, yes: reading the code in, and then reformatting it back out according to the style guide (like autopep8 and yapf, gofmt, and so on).

Comment: Is there any prettier plugin for VS code, like there is for javascript. I am facing this problem. I get error all the time for the indentation in my solidity code not adhering to the standard ( 4 spaces )

Answer (score 7):

There's a work in progress towards a plugin for [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) that formats solidity code: https://github.com/prettier-solidity/prettier-plugin-solidity As with prettier, the goal is to have an opinionated tool that takes your code, builds its AST and prints it again.

*(Disclaimer: I'm one of the contributors)*

Comment: I think this is more than WIP now! Just tried it out and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 4):

If you use atom.io there is a linter: https://atom.io/packages/linter-solidity

And for syntax highlighting goodies: https://atom.io/packages/language-ethereum

Comment: Thanks! That only shows lint output, though, and doesn't format code, right?

Comment: updated to add a code formatter

Comment: The highlighter performs syntax highlighting, but also doesn't format code.

Comment: You're right, I thought it was that package, but it was another package:https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify which I configured for solidity.

Comment: Ah, how did you configure it?

Comment: Look at the configuration instructions on that page, you should be able to configure it to do most of the things you want.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/alexstep/SublimeLinter-contrib-solium

Solium linter plugin for sublime text

Answer (score 3):

The 2023 answer is to use `forge fmt`. https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/config/formatter

Do that once and be liberated from this issue

Answer (score 2):

This is available now for IntelliJ (and related IDEs):

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9475-intellij-solidity

Answer (score 1):

This is [a linter](https://github.com/tokenhouse/solhint) that provides security, style and best practice validations.

You may install it with

```
npm install -g solhint
```

For validation you need put in arguments glob expression of path to your code

```
solhint *.sol
```

I believe this tool with be useful for your project!

Comment: welcome to the community :) look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) for more guide on formatting

Comment: Solhint is awesome, but OP asked for a formatter not a linter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use YAKINDU Soliditiy Tools, its open source and it has some other interesting features even if it is currently in beta phase.

https://medium.com/solidity-ide/yakindu-solidity-tools-beta-released-dbcc76307bc0